# Sync worker threads in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, worker-thread

I have some code for playing with "worker threads" (Node js). When in app.js in loop I set condition i<100000000, my second thread do not start before first thread not finish. How in Node js work sync threads ? And how I can use two and more threads on parallel ?

```js
const { Worker } = require('worker_threads');
const path = require('path');

const WORKERS_NUMBER = 2;

for (var i = 1; i <= WORKERS_NUMBER ; i++) {
  const w = new Worker(path.join(__dirname, './app.js'), { workerData: { id: i } });
  w.addListener("message",(message)=>{console.log(message);});
}
```

```js
const { workerData, parentPort } = require('worker_threads');

const id = workerData.id;

console.log(`Worker ${id} initializad.`);
let i=0;
while (i<10) {
  i++;
  process.nextTick((i)=>{    
    parentPort.postMessage( `${id}:${i}` );
  },i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually sync the threads' execution.
You can do it by listening on a certain message you'd send from workers to the main thread and using a counter to know when all the threads are done.

Otherwise, you can use the [microjob](https://github.com/wilk/microjob) lib that easily wraps the worker thread execution inside a Promise, so the synchronisation becomes trivial.

Take a look to the examples inside the [docs](https://github.com/wilk/microjob/blob/master/GUIDE.md).